# Google Cloud Platform: How do I add another node to an elasticsearch deployment?

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I used the GCC one-click deployments to create an elasticsearch cluster with 3 nodes. Now I'd like to add another node to the deployment for horizontal scaling. This seems to be one of the features Google advertises themselves:

"This means you can expand your Elasticsearch deployment simply by adding new nodes. This expansion of your cluster — or in in the case of a hardware failure, reduction — results in automatic reconfiguration of your document indices across the cluster." - https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/01/Deploy-Elasticsearch-on-Google-Compute-Engine.html

But how can I achieve that? The node instances cannot be cloned and if I try that manually from a snapshot, the instances won't even start up (connection refused error).

It does also not seem that the deployment can be edited from the Google Developer Console, or am I missing something?

Comment: Which one-click deployment template did you use to start your cluster?

Comment: The official one from elasticsearch (not Bitnami).

Comment: The click-to-deploy feature for elasticsearch cluster is only meant for deployment. Unfortunately, there is no click-to-manage for any post-deployment configuration changes. If you would like to add or remove a node, you will have to do it manually. You can refer to [this elasticsearch doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_scale_horizontally.html) for more information on scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `Instance groups` menu under `Compute Engine`? There should be an instance group for your cluster saying it has 3 machines and you should be able to edit the instance group to add more of them.

Comment: That would make sense, but there is no instance group for these instances and there is also no instance template specified for them (different from other, non-elastic instances we have that are part of instance groups).